# Generate a random number and store it

Tags: java, random

In Java, how would I generate a random number and then store that number? I've been trying to use this:

```
public void obstacleAvoidance() {

    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    double leftSpeed, rightSpeed;
    int turn = rnd.nextInt() % 10;

    while (turn > 0) {
        leftSpeed = -SPEED;
        rightSpeed = SPEED;
        setSpeed(leftSpeed, rightSpeed);
        turn--;
    }

}
```

But it seems like everything the loop runs, turn produces a different number.

Comment: This code looks right to me.  `turn`s value should not change in the while loop.

Comment: Not enough code shown. What happens inside of the loop? Are you reassigning `turn` inside of the loop?

Comment: That code is fine you must be doing something else. Can you post code which demonstrates the turn variable changing ?

Comment: You *are* generating a random integer between 0 and 9 and you *are* storing it in the `turn` variable. What is your question?

Comment: I wonder if this is how SkyNet became self-aware, randomly mutating code.. Bet everyone thought the code looked fine there too!

Comment: Use rnd.nextInt(10) instead of rnd.nextInt()%10.  Using the modulus operator introduces bias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. `turn` will not change in the loop by itself unless you change it (by doing `turn++;` or something like that). You can do this

```
final int turn = rnd.nextInt() % 10;
```

to safeguard against changes in the loop.

Comment: well there is a turn--; so that would change turns value

Comment: @Wolfcow initial version of the question did not show what the while loop was doing.

Comment: Ok, gotcha, that would make sense then =) sorry

Answer (score 1):

final int turn = rnd.nextInt() % 10; 
but this will cause infinite loop....because turn will always remain greater than zero...
You can do this:
int turn1 = rnd.nextInt() % 10; 
turn = turn1;

```
while (turn > 0) {
    leftSpeed = -SPEED;
    rightSpeed = SPEED;
    setSpeed(leftSpeed, rightSpeed);
    turn--;
}
```